# Displaying unserialize value in blade Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, serialization

i have serialize data in my code, to make me more flexible in inputing data

but i still dont know how to displaying serialize data in blade

this is my serialize data

[image]

this is my controller

```
public function preview($id)
  {
    $form = NewForm::whereId($id)->firstOrFail();
    // return $form;

    if($form->is_published)
    {
      $data['form'] = $form;
      $data['participant'] = $form->participant;
      $data['idea'] = $form->idea;
      $data['character'] = $form->character;
      $data['link'] = $form->link;
      $data['images'] = $form->images;
      $data['finance'] = $form->finance;
      $data['competition'] = $form->competition;
      $data['competition_list'] = $form->competition_list;
      $data['audition'] = $form->audition;
      $data['confirmation'] = $form->confirmation;
      $data['survey'] = unserialize($form->survey);

      // return $data;

      $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.form', $data);

      return $pdf->stream('DSCX'.sprintf("%04d", $form->id).'.pdf');
    }

    return 'Proposal not published';
  }
```

this is my blade

```
<label>Survey</label>
   <p>{{ $survey->source }}</p>
</td>
```

when i do

> unserialize($form->survey)
> it is returning this error
> unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 251 bytes

how do i display the data? thank you

Answer (score 0):

You will need to call `unserialize()` on that string to convert it to an appropriate array, you can then display your array properties.

Do something like this in your controller, and pass the data to your view:

```
$survey = unserialize($form->survey);
```

Then foreach through that array in your blade view:

```
@foreach ($survey as $line)
    <p>{{ $line }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Comment: what should i put in "prop"?

Comment: i put my controller code in my question, please review it. thanks

Comment: I'd print_r $source out now and see what keys you have :) You can then access those keys in your view.  OR in your view, just foreach through $source would be another option.

Comment: Updated my answer to show how you would foreach through that unserialized $survey array. Also changed names to match yours.

Comment: it is not returning the value. it's just returning an Integer